# How to create a view to count comments per user?

Tags: views, 8, users, comments

I am trying to create a view with a table that shows all the users and the total number of comments that user posted in descending order. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I spent hours on this already...

Can anybody point me to the right direction?

The closest I got is I created a view of comments so far with the author name that I tried to aggregate. But I am getting all sorts of weird results.

Comment: Without knowing what you did so far we can't tell you what you are doing wrong...

Comment: @leymannx Thank you for your quick reply. I got it working after all. I appreciate your willingness to help :) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I got it!** Sharing my way ;)

What I did:

1. Created a view of comments of my type.
2. As fields, I added Author uid **twice**.
3. Set aggregation (COUNT) on the second Author uid.
4. Added a sort criteria for aggregated (Count) Author uid as descending.

woala... Wasn't that hard after all :)

Comment: This is not working for me. If I compare counts vs a comment view searching by uid, the totals are quite different.